# Symfony 4 - Override maxSizeMessage in validator

Tags: image, symfony, validation, upload, symfony4

I try to override the *maxSizeMessage* atttribute from File in a *Symfony* 4.2 project however, it is the default message who is returned by the framework ("The file is too large ({{ size }} {{ suffix }}). Allowed maximum size is {{ limit }} {{ suffix }}").

This is my validator configuration for this FormType :

```
# config\validator\validator.yaml
App\Application\Form\Command\PropertyPicture\PropertyAddPictureCommand:
    properties:
        image: 
            - Image:
                maxSize: 10M
                maxSizeMessage: "Image size over 10M"
                mimeTypes: [image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/bmp]
                mimeTypesMessage: "Image extension not valid"
                uploadErrorMessage: "An error has been encounted during the process"
```

[EDIT for Michał Tomczuk commentary (2019/04/08)]

This is the "FormType" object in this project (it is a DDD architecture with POMM) :

```
class PropertyAddPictureCommand
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $link;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $filename;

    /**
     * @var Property
     */
    public $property;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $pathname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $directory;

    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $image;
}
```

[END EDIT for Michał Tomczuk commentary (2019/04/08)]

[EDIT for Michał Tomczuk commentary (2019/04/09)]

This is the FormType object use (the object get before is the values passed in $options array) in the project :

```
class CommandType extends AbstractType 
{
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'name' => 'command_type',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        foreach (get_object_vars($options['data']) as $key => $value) {
            $builder->add($key);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the form object in the controller :

```
$uploadedFile = $request->files->get('image');
$propertyId = $property->getIdValue();
$directory = 'group'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->getUser()->getGroupId().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'property'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$propertyId;

$filename = $propertyId.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension();

$command = new PropertyAddPictureCommand();
$command->link = $this->getParameter('amazon_s3.bucket_url').'images/'.$directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename;
$command->filename = $filename;
$command->property = $property;
$command->pathname = $uploadedFile->getPathname();
$command->directory = $directory;

$form = $this->createForm(CommandType::class, $command, ['data_class' => PropertyAddPictureCommand::class]);
$form->submit($request->request->all() + ['image' => $uploadedFile], false);

if (!$form->isValid()) {
    throw new NotValidFormException($form);
}
```

[END EDIT for Michał Tomczuk commentary (2019/04/09)]

I expected to show "Image size over 10M" message when the image size is over 10M.

Comment: You've placed the validation on a form type, instead you should place it on the underlying data object. Could you paste the code for controller, form type and data class that this form type handles?

Comment: I have updated the first post for you @MichałTomczuk

Comment: How are you calling the validation? Do you have a controller with that form and you simply do `$form->handleRequest()` to run the validation or maybe do you call the validator yourself? Are you getting the (default) error when a file is more than 10M (so are other properties of the `Image` constraint working)? Is the error message you are getting exactly as you wrote, or does it have values for placeholders?

Comment: The error message for Mime type work perfectly and the message which I have mentioned have values for placeholders.

Comment: In the controller you've pasted you are submitting a `PropertyDeletePictureCommand` instead of `PropertyAddPictureCommand `. I guess it's still just an example, but I'd like to see the actual code that handles the `PropertyAddPictureCommand`.

Comment: Sorry, I write the bad code. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a property path issue.

Your form has a name - `command_type`, which means that every input name is preceeded with it, so instead of appending `image` to the request, try appending `command_type[image]`.

I think you could also simply map the image to the command object:

```php
$command->image = $uploadedFile;
```

In this case you don't need to append the `image` property to the request.

Comment: This is not work, when I remove ```['image' => $uploadedFile]``` in submit form instruction and add ```$command->image = $uploadedFile;```. I have "Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty" error message.

Comment: And if you change `['image' => $uploadedFile]` to `['command_type[image]' => $uploadedFile]`?

Comment: With this modification, I have this message when I try to upload an image : ```This form must not contain additional fields```.

Comment: Ok so it seems like adding the `['image' => $uploadedFile]` will not do anything, as it is not adding it to the actual `PropertyAddPictureCommand `. Therefore the only option is to map the uploaded image to the `$command` itself. But you have an error about an empty filename (and probably the file). So another question - am I correct that you are handling the file upload (`$uploadedFile = $request->files->get('image');`) and the command form in the same request? Also - can you paste the contents of `$uploadedFile` right before `$form = $this->createForm`?

Comment: The ```$request->files->get('image')``` is not null but i don't set ```$image``` attribute define in PropertyAddPictureCommand who is an UploadedFile object during the processing (if I read the code who I have found) and if I try to set this attribute, I have an error (display before in a commentary).

Comment: Can you trace where this `file_get_contents()` error is comming from?